# Azure's Graph api passwordprofile NULL for b2c users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Users sign up/login via Azure AD B2C using Identity provider Local Account-Email.

I can see users signed up (with their password) for the tenant:
[image]
When I run [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management) ["Manage User Accounts with Graph API"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api) to check for local identity passwordProfiles they show null. My assumption is this property is automatically populated when a user creates the password same as other [User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) resources.

Can someone give me some guidance what I'm missing?

```cs
    public static async Task GetUserByIssuerAssignedID(AppSettings config, GraphServiceClient graphClient)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter user sign-in name (username or email address): ");
            string userName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine($"Looking for user with sign-in name '{userName}'...");

            try
            {
                // Get user by sign-in name
                var result = await graphClient.Users
                    .Request()
                    .Filter($"identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{userName}' and c/issuer eq '{config.TenantId}')")
                    .Select(e => new
                    {
                        e.PasswordProfile,
                        e.DisplayName,
                        e.Id,
                        e.Identities
                    })
                    .GetAsync();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
                }
```

[image]
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an expected result.

Azure AD B2C doesn't require the local identity users to change password next sign in. As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#password-profile-property) says:

> The property must set to `.forceChangePasswordNextSignIn false`.

Set `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn` as `true` is meaningless. In this case, `passwordProfile` won't be visible through GET method of Microsoft Graph API.

You can quickly verify it in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

For example, if you create a user with `"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true` in an Azure AD tenant, you will get `passwordProfile` in the result.

If you create a user with `"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true` in an Azure AD B2C tenant, you can get `"passwordProfile"` in the result but the password is null.

```
"passwordProfile": {
    "password": null,
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa": false
}
```

We can never get user password using Microsoft Graph API or any other official API. Azure AD won't store password. So you can't get it.

Comment: thank you @Allen, I don't understand, why is forceChangePasswordNextSignIn =true meaningless if forceChangePasswordNextSignIn =false means it doesn't require users to change password next sign in?

Comment: @SergioSolorzano Yes. You are correct. In B2C DisablePasswordExpiration is set by default in the password policies, and forceChangePasswordNextLogin should always be set to false. This is so that the user is recognized and can be authenticated. So setting forceChangePasswordNextSignIn =true is meaningless. See https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44325#issuecomment-565267153. So based on this fact, forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false will lead to `"passwordProfile": null`.

Comment: thank you @Allen , I upvoted the feature to change pwd, so as passwordProfile is null can you please share guidance to get the user password? I'm happy to create a new stackoverflow post if you prefer. thanks a bunch for your help

Comment: @SergioSolorzano I'm sorry for that I have made a mistake. In fact we can set `forceChangePasswordNextLogin` as `true` through Microsoft Graph API instead of Custom Policy. And We can also get `passwordProfile` in the result. It is like this `"passwordProfile": {
        "password": null,
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa": false
    }`. BUT please note that we can never get user password using Microsoft Graph API or other official API. Azure AD won't store password. So you can't get it.

Comment: @SergioSolorzano I have updated my answer. If it's helpful,you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: thanks a lot @Allen Wu if Azure doesn't store pwds how can it know whether a password is good or bad?

Comment: @SergioSolorzano When you change a password, Azure AD will verify the password. But it  won't be stored in Azure AD. I think maybe it will be stored as a hash code.